# How does Anaconda handle pip-installed packages and other customisation when Python minor version changes?

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, versioning, conda

Let's say I have an Anaconda Python installation, say it's Python 3.7, and I :

- pip-install a couple of packages, which end up in `~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages`.
- Add a custom `.pth` file to site-packages to make modules stored somewhere else included in the Python import path.

At a later date, Python 3.8 is released. I type `conda install python==3.8`. Conda uninstalls all the Python 3.7 versions of all the packages it tracks, and installs the Python 3.8 versions instead, which by then are in its repositories.

What happens to the packages I pip-installed? Are they just left in `~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages`, where Python 3.8 will not see them (It is looking in `~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages`)? What happens to my `.pth` file? Is it similarly left there where it will have no effect?

I distribute Python software which during installation, adds its module directories (which are stored elsewhere on the system) to the Python search path by adding such a `.pth` file to site-packages of the Python interpreter that was used to install it. It also depends on a number of packages not in the conda repositories that our documentation recommends the user installs via pip. I'm concerned future Python updates that might seem innocuous to users of this software (who are almost exclusively using Anaconda) may break the installation of our software.

Whilst this software has been in use for years, it was on Python 2.7 for so long that I haven't seen what happens in this situation. The current version of anaconda also seems to have either a bug or an unresolvable dependency such that it just hangs if I try to *downgrade* Python to a different version, so I haven't been able to test to see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Copying and pasting from an answer I got [here](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/anaconda/BMt_cLlzpi4):

---

> At a later date, Python 3.8 is released. I type conda install python==3.8.
>   Conda uninstalls all the Python 3.7 versions of all the packages it tracks,
>   and installs the Python 3.8 versions instead, which by then are in its
>   repositories.

are you sure it uninstalls the 3.7 versions? but anyway:

What happens to the packages I pip-installed? Are they just left in

> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages, where Python 3.8 will not see them
>   (It is looking in ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages)? What happens to
>   my .pth file? Is it similarly left there where it will have no effect?

yes, they will either be left there in 3.7, or deleted. As a rule, 3.7
packages are not necessarily compatible with 3.8, so you don't want them
moved.

you will want folks to repeat your isntall process with 3.8, jsut like you
would with a non-conda based system.

I distribute Python software which during installation, adds its module

> directories (which are stored elsewhere on the system) to the Python search
>   path by adding such a .pth file to site-packages of the Python interpreter
>   that was used to install it.

why not make them packages that install the usual way ? For that matter,
you could supply conda packages as well, if you want to fully support conda.

> It also depends on a number of packages not in the conda repositories that
>   our documentation recommends the user installs via pip.

It's a bit of a lift but you could contribute those packages to
conda-forge, and then your users could have a an all-conda install, which
would make all of this easier.

> I'm concerned future Python updates that might seem innocuous to users of
>   this software (who are almost exclusively using Anaconda) may break the
>   installation of our software.

I think that is indeed a risk -- but if your users are mostly using
Anaconda, then providing them with all the conda pacakges they need
(including your own) would make this al easier.